# Elastic Search using a lot of memory despite stored size of index is very small

Tags: elasticsearch

I know when elastic search start it take %50 of OS memory,
The stored size of my index in elastic search is about 100 MB, But when I call the API "_nodes/stats" I found the "heap_used_in_bytes" is about 3GB

I know that elastic search use some memory for indexing and caching process, but that is very high for the small size of stored index !

Why elatic search is use all of these memory, although stored index size is very small ?
And there are any way to avoid these high memory usage ?

Comment: when you say stored size is of 100 MB is it single index or all ?

Comment: It is single index, when I request API "/_cat/indices?v",It get the stored size of my alone index 100 MB

Comment: "I know when elastic search start it take %50 of OS memory" - that's not entirely accurate. it'd be useful if you shared some info like your node stats output, and the cat indices output